# List index out of range error in splunk API call

Tags: api, splunk, outofrangeexception

I am trying to get the result of a search query from splunk. But when i try to get the session key, i am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "splunkenter.py", line 18, in <module>
    sessionkey = minidom.parseString(servercontent).getElementsByTagName('sessionKey')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
IndexError: list index out of range
```

splunkenter.py:

```
import urllib 
import httplib2 
import time 
import re from time 
import localtime,strftime 
from xml.dom import minidom 
import json 
baseurl = 'abc.haihd.com:8000'
username = 'xxxxx' 
password = 'xxxxx' 
myhttp = httplib2.Http() 

#Step 1: Get a session key 
servercontent = myhttp.request(baseurl + '/services/auth/login', 'POST', headers={}, body=urllib.urlencode({'username':username, 'password':password}))[1]
sessionkey = 

minidom.parseString(servercontent).getElementsByTagName('sessionKey')[0].childNo‌​des[0].nodeValue 
print "====>sessionkey: %s <====" % sessionke
```

Can anybody tell me where is the problem lying. I am very new to API's.

Comment: can you show the source code of splunkenter.py. `Value IndexError: list index out of range` means that your list is None

Comment: import urllib
import httplib2
import time
import re
from time import localtime,strftime
from xml.dom import minidom
import json
baseurl = 'http://abc.haihd.com:8000'
username = 'xxxxx'
password = 'xxxxx'
myhttp = httplib2.Http()
#Step 1: Get a session key
servercontent = myhttp.request(baseurl + '/services/auth/login', 'POST',
headers={}, body=urllib.urlencode({'username':username, 'password':password}))[1]
sessionkey = minidom.parseString(servercontent).getElementsByTagName('sessionKey')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
print "====>sessionkey: %s <====" % sessionkey

Comment: To debug this source code. you should add `print minidom.parseString(servercontent).getElementsByTagName('sessionKey')` before line 18 and show me the output

Comment: I ran the code like you said and i got '[ ]' as output.

Comment: This is the last few lines of the code that i ran.   servercontent = myhttp.request(baseurl + '/services/auth/login', 'POST',
headers={}, body=urllib.urlencode({'username':username, 'password':password}))[1]
#sessionkey = minidom.parseString(servercontent).getElementsByTagName('sessionKey')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
print minidom.parseString(servercontent).getElementsByTagName('sessionKey')
#print "====>sessionkey: %s <====" % sessionkey